# Can't unmute sound after playing video

Tags: 12.04, sound, settings

I'm running Ubuntu on a Toshiba C660 (4GB RAM, Intel Core i5). My soundboard is integrated and after trying to play a song on youtube my volume is muted. I can't unmute it (appears like it's unmuted , but it's mute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo killall pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Comment: didnt work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, I just recently upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 . In my case i was able to hear sound on System -> Sound -> Test Sound. But I couldn't hear a sound on youtube or while playing mp3's on rhythmbox.

I followed instruction at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure
solution for 12.04
And now everything is back to normal.

I hope it helps

Cheers,

Bram

Comment: it works now. i restarted my pc and it worked. but it seems it`s doing this constantly. i`ll follow the instructions you gave me :) thanx !

Comment: My Dell XPS 17 (l702x) displays the same behaviour under 12.04 (no video sound, test sound in applet OK). I'll try the instruction at the link above, it's a shame that they look so lengthy and involved (oh well). Cheers, Rich.

Comment: 18 steps to fix audio?  and, in the end, audio STILL doesnt work.  ubuntu will be a great OS, once it is ready.  if you're not a total geek, ubuntu is at best a backup system for when windows crashes or you are navigating high-risk seas.

Answer (score 2):

Given your sparse information and my limited knowledge on the topic, I can only offer a possible solution from my own experience: pulseaudio and flash do seem to cause problems from time to time. Killing one or the other solves this problem often for me:
e.g.

run `pkill pulseaudio` in a terminal and then reload the youtube video.

Comment: thank you :) it`s not only on youtube. if i open a player it doesn`t work either :)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with you tube video sound.there was an x next to the speaker icon beneath the video which i could not get rid of.i finally clicked on to the icon and dragged it to the right and the sound came back.